# How do you destructure a map into key-value pairs without knowing the keys in Clojure?

Tags: dictionary, clojure, destructuring

Suppose I have a map like so

```
{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}
```

I'd like to map over this like so (note - non-working pseudocode):

```
(mapcat (fn [[:key key-a][:value value-a]] (println "key: " key-a "\n value: " value-a )))
```

Is this possible without getting the keys of the function first, mapping over those and reading them back from the function?

My question is: **How do you destructure a map into key-value pairs without knowing the keys in Clojure?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(seq {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
;([:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 3])
```

Calling `seq` on a map gives you a sequence of key-value pairs. The `seq` call is usually implicit.

The pairs

- need not be in the entered order;
- are actually `MapEntry`s, which behave as pairs.

Thus

```
(type (first {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}))
;clojure.lang.MapEntry
```

Your pseudocode

```
(mapcat (fn [[:key key-a][:value value-a]] (println "key: " key-a "\n value: " value-a )))
```

... needs several repairs:

- Supply the omitted final argument - the collection to which `map` 
  is applied.
- Simply destructure each `MapEntry` as a pair to get at
  key and value.
- Use `map` instead of `mapcat` to apply the function to each pair.
  It's just lucky that `mapcat` works at all.
- Use `dorun` to force the sequence to evaluate and to throw it away as
  it does so. The REPL does the former for you, but a running
  application need not.

This gives us

```
(dorun
 (map 
  (fn [[key-a value-a]] (println "key: " key-a " value: " value-a ))
  {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}))
```

Which *prints*

```
key:  :a  value:  1
key:  :c  value:  3
key:  :b  value:  2
```

... and *returns* `nil`.

Answer (score 5):

When you `map` over a map, each element is a vector containing two values: the key and the value. You destructure each element with a vector like this:

```
(def m {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
(map (fn [[key value]] (str "key: " key " > value: " value-a)) m)
```

Note that the function passed to `map` returns a String value, instead of your call to `println`, since we're trying to transform the collection passed in by applying a function to each value. You could pass the collection returned by `map` to `prn` to debug the value, though the REPL will print it out for you anyway.