# How do I conditionally update keys and values in a Clojure map based on the key name?

Tags: clojure, hashmap, etl

I have a map and the keys are strings. If the key contains the word "kg" I want to multiply the value by 2.2 and then replace "kg" with "lb" in the key. I can't figure out how to iterate over the map in a way that I can conditionally update it.

Example map:

```
{"id" ("7215" "74777" "7219"),
 "weight-kg" ("150" "220" "530"),
 "time-seconds" ("1900" "2" "770")}
```

Desired output

```
{"id" ("7215" "74777" "7219"),
 "weight-lb" ("330" "485" "1168"),
 "time-seconds" ("1900" "2" "770")}
```

I've tried `update`, `for` `map` and `reduce-kv`. Project requirement is to not use the string library, which is why there is `re-find`. These are only attempts at changing the values. Since I can't change the values, I haven't attempted changing the keys.

```
(defn kg->lb [m k]
    (if (re-find #"kg" k)
      (map #(update m % * 2.2))))

(defn kg2->lb2 [m]
    (reduce-kv #(if (re-find #"kg" %)
                  (update % * 2.2)) {} m)

(map #(if (re-find #"kg" %)
        (update % * 2.2)) m)

(for [k (keys m)]
    (if (re-find #"kg" k)
      (update m k #(* % 2.2))))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data:

```
(def data {"id"           ["7215" "74777" "7219"],
           "weight-kg"    ["150" "220" "530"],
           "time-seconds" ["1900" "2" "770"]})
```

Helper function to convert a string (kg amount) to string (lb amount):

```
(defn kg->lb [kg-string]
  (-> kg-string
      parse-long
      (* 2.2)
      int
      str))
```

The most important function is [`reduce-kv`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce-kv).

If you find `"kg"` in key, you will replace that with `"lb"` and map helper function over all values.

If you don't find `"kg"` in key, you will just assoc that entry without change.

```
(reduce-kv (fn [m k v]
             (if (re-find #"kg" k)
               (assoc m (str/replace k #"kg" "lb")
                        (map kg->lb v))
               (assoc m k v)))
           {} 
           data)
```

I think I passed *Project requirement is to not use the string library*, except for `(str/replace k #"kg" "lb")`, which you can replace with [`String/replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)) interop: `(.replace k "kg" "lb")`.

**EDIT:** Solution with [`map`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map) and [`into`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into):

```
(defn update-entry [[k v]]
  (if (re-find #"kg" k)
    [(.replace k "kg" "lb") (map kg->lb v)]
    [k v]))

(->> data
     (map update-entry)
     (into {}))
```

[Transducer](https://clojure.org/reference/transducers) version:

```
(into {} (map update-entry) data)
```

Comment: Can you explain the update-entry solution? Why is  k v passed in as a vector?

Comment: `[k v]` in argument vector is a way to [destructure](https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring) map entry- see also [How do you destructure a map into key-value pairs without knowing the keys in Clojure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28408743/how-do-you-destructure-a-map-into-key-value-pairs-without-knowing-the-keys-in-cl)- then you can create hash-map from these pairs with `into`.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it a bit differently.  First, I'd convert the strings to integers using the Java function `Long/parseLong`:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.core :as t]
    ))

(defn parse-vec-longs
  [v]
  (mapv #(Long/parseLong %) v))

(verify
  (is= (parse-vec-longs ["150" "220" "530"])
    [150 220 530]))
```

Then I would write the code to convert the kg vals to lb vals.  At the end, just use `dissoc` to get rid of the kg data, then `assoc` to add in the new lb data:

```
(defn convert-kg-lb
  [data]
  (let-spy-pretty [kg-vals (get data "weight-kg")
                   lb-vals (mapv #(Math/round (* 2.2 %)) kg-vals)
                   result  (t/it-> data
                             (dissoc it "weight-kg")
                             (assoc it "weight-lb" lb-vals))]
    result))

(verify
  (let [data-str        {"id"           ["7215" "74777" "7219"]
                         "weight-kg"    ["150" "220" "530"]
                         "time-seconds" ["1900" "2" "770"]}
        data-parsed     (t/map-vals data-str #(parse-vec-longs %))
        expected-parsed {"id"           [7215 74777 7219]
                         "weight-kg"    [150 220 530]
                         "time-seconds" [1900 2 770]}
        expected-out    {"id"           [7215 74777 7219]
                         "weight-lb"    [330 484 1166]
                         "time-seconds" [1900 2 770]}
        result          (convert-kg-lb data-parsed)]
    (is= data-parsed expected-parsed)
    (is= (spyx-pretty result) (spyx-pretty expected-out))))
```

Normally, you'd also replace all the string keys with keywords as well, so `"lb"` => `:lb`.